# volume/mixer manipulation in GNOME

Tags: gnome, mixer

What is the Right Way for a well-behaved program in a GNOME environment to manipulate the mixer? (volume, muting, etc)

DBus? ALSA directly? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say PulseAudio (see [2.5. Volume Control Integrated with PulseAudio](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/2.26/#rnusers.volume) in Gnome 2.26 Release Notes).